# Is there any relationship between image input dimension, filter/kernel size and feature map?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, keras, image-processing, convolution

Is there any relation between image input dimension (height, width), filter/kernel size and feature map?
If for example I have this code:

```
#block1, 128x128
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(h,w,3))
    conv11 = layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation="relu",padding="same")(inputs) # (3,3) is the kernal size 
    conv12= layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation="relu",padding="same")(conv11) # 16 Integer,the number of output filters in the convolution
    conv13= layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation="relu",padding="same")(conv12)
    pool1 = layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv13)
    drop1 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(pool1)
```

My input is 128x128, kernel_size is 3x3 and number of applied filters is 16.

So after performing the first convolution how can I know the size of my gotten output before performing the second convolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Keras, `padding="same"` means that the output width and output height will be the same as the input (in your case 128x128). You chose the output image depth (num of channels) to be 16, so the output shape will be 128x128x16 .

more info is available here [Keras Conv2D layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)

This is Keras's implementation, the answer can be different for each library's implementation

Comment: and normally 'pool1 = layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv13)' will divide the image size to 2 ? so we will have 64x64x16

Comment: yes, look at the examples here - https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/max_pooling2d/

Comment: Sorry, one more point as I understand from your response is that the number of channels is the same as the number of applied filters no?

Comment: yes, for each filter there is an output channel